# How to convert a negative decimal number to octal base without any helping funtions

Tags: c

I'm implementing the printf function and now am stuck at the conversion of the negative base 10 number into a base 8 octal number, below i placed the piece of code which is working just fine in regard to converting a positive decimal number to octal just like the printf

> my ft_printf => 15 octal => 017

> original printf => 15 octal => 017

but regarding the negative numbers:

> my ft_printf => -15 octal => 0-17

> original printf => -15 octal => 037777777761

what should i modify with my function in order for it to print the negative numbers just like the printf does thank you!!!

```c
void    process_octal(unsigned int n)
{
    char    *str;
    int     oct = 0;
    int     rem = 0;
    int     place = 1;

    while (n)
    {
        rem = n % 8;
        oct = oct + rem * place;
        n = n / 8;
        place = place * 10;    
    }
    str = ft_itoa(oct);
    ft_putstr_fd(str, 1);
}
```

Comment: In "real" printf, `%o` takes an `unsigned` value, so it's never printed as negative.  Is that what you want?

Comment: but even though the printf does give a value which 037777777761 for the -15 input how does it get it

Comment: I'm surprised you got `021` (what does that even mean?), but if you want it to work more like real printf, your first step would be to change `int n` to `unsigned int n`.  But...

Comment: 037777777761 is [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: It looks like you're first converting the decimal number 15 to the decimal number 17, and then printing it as if it were a decimal number (that is, using `ft_itoa`).  I would say that's just the wrong way to do it.  Among other things, how will you possibly handle `%x` using that approach?

Comment: @SteveSummit the itoa is just printing the number, what i have written inside the while is doing its function which is to convert a positive base 10 number into a base 8 octal number

Comment: @SteveSummit the output wasn't 021 but 0-17

Comment: I understand -- but in my opinion, this is a very, very poor way to go about it.  I ask again: how would you handle base 16 (that is, `%x`) this way?

Comment: When you have an integer `n` that you want to print in base 8, you should convert it to a string of digits (and print those digits).  You should not "convert" it to another integer that is "in octal".  That number that came in, `n`, was an integer.  It was not in decimal or octal, it was just a number.  I understand why you're trying to do what you're trying to do, and it's a popular technique, but it's confusing, misleading, and ultimately wrong.  (Sorry.)

Comment: @SteveSummit i have a hole implementation for the printf with a function that's handling the %x and %X and %#x and %#X and its working fine the only problem am having is with the negative conversion thats why i just placed the snippet for the %#o function

Comment: In your loop, I would get rid of `oct = oct + rem * place;`, and replace it with `printf("%d", rem);  (That's not a complete solution, but it's a step in the right direction.)

Comment: @SteveSummit can you explain what you mean with converting it into a string and then printing them

Comment: If `%x` is working fine, you should be able to go through it, changing all 16's to 8's, and it should work for `%o`.

Comment: i cant use printf

Comment: Maybe someone else can help you, I've got to go back to work.

Comment: Please take my suggestion, and use `printf` *temporarily*.  It will be a step in the right direction.  Eventually you can get rid of `printf`, and use `putchar` instead.  But you have a few other problems you have to solve, and things to learn, first.

Comment: @SteveSummit yeah for sure

Comment: What is your `ft_itoa()` signature? You can't get the same output as printf unless it takes unsigned argument.

Comment: it just prints the number

Comment: You seem to be confusing decimal and binary numbers.  You should be using "native binary" numbers (such as int or long) throughout, and only using decimal or octal (or hex) for strings, when converting between strings and and numbers.

Comment: @ChrisDodd my problem wasn't with the string conversion it was with the base conversion

Comment: @Nizz: there is no such thing as a base conversion that is not a string conversion.  The whole concept of base only makes sense when talking about strings -- "numbers" in the abstract *HAVE NO BASE*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple function to convert number to any base (limited to the number of available digit symbols).

```
char *reverse(char *ptr, size_t length)
{
    char *str = ptr;
    if(ptr && length)
    {
        char *end = ptr + length - 1;
        while(end > str)
        {
            char tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}


char *convert(char *buff, long long val, unsigned base)
{
    const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
    int negative = val < 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    if(base < 2 || base > sizeof(digits) - 1) return NULL;

    do
    {
        buff[count++] = digits[abs(val % base)];
        val /= base;
    }while(val);
    if(negative) buff[count++] = '-';
    buff[count] = 0;
    return reverse(buff, count);
    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wz15h4x41

After OPs comment:

function which will print signed or unsigned representation of the value depending on the `asUnsigned` parameter:

```
char *convert(char *buff, long long val, unsigned base, int asUnsigned)
{
    const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
    int negative = val < 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    if(base < 2 || base > sizeof(digits) - 1) return NULL;

    do
    {
        buff[count++] = digits[asUnsigned ? ((unsigned)val) % base : abs(val % base)];
        val = (asUnsigned ? (unsigned)val : val) / base;
    }while(val);
    if(!asUnsigned && negative) buff[count++] = '-';
    buff[count] = 0;
    return reverse(buff, count);
    
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MdMGerTTs

```
int main(void) {
    char str[32];
    printf("%s\n", convert(str, -15, 8, 1));  
    printf("%s\n", convert(str, -15, 8, 0));  

}
```

Result:

```
37777777761
-17
```

Comment: but the output isnt like the original printf which is 037777777761 my function does give me the same output as yours

Comment: You asked to print negative numbers

Comment: in the octal form just like the printf that was my question

Comment: @Nizz see the second part of my answer. Universal function. You can treat the number as negative or unsigned depending on the parameter.

Comment: thank you for your help sorry for the confusion

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica indeed

Answer (score 0):

> I'm implementing the printf function and now am stuck at the conversion of the negative base 10 number into a base 8 octal number

This implies OP is incorrectly getting the argument.

With `"%o"`, `"%x"`, `"%X"`,  `"%u"`, the corresponding argument is  type `unsigned`, not `int`.

With a proper `printf()`, there is no printing of a *signed* integer with specifiers `oxXu`.

Code attempting to pass a negative integer to match a `oxXu` results in *undefined behavior* (UB).  A common UB is to treat the *signed* argument as if it was *unsigned*.